# Convergence in $L^1$ of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I have to see if the following sequence of functions is convergent in the space $L^1[(0,\infty)]$

$$f_n(x)= n\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2x^2}\right)}{x^3}$$

By definition, $f_n(x)$ is convergent in $L^1[(0,\infty)]$ if and only if:

For any $\epsilon >0, \exists n_0 \in N\,|$ any $n>n_0 ||f_n -f||_1 < \epsilon$

$$||f_n -f||_1= \int_{(0,\infty)}\left|\frac{n}{x^3}\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2x^2}\right)\right|dx= e^{-(n/2x^2)}\Big|_{(\infty,0)}$$

How can I continue?

Thank you very much

Comment: Substitute the limits of integration and finish the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:
$$||f_n -f||_1= \int_{(0,\infty)}\left|\frac{n}{x^3}e^{\left(-\frac{n}{2x^2}\right)}\right|dx = \cdots$$

For any $n > 0$, we have that:
$$||f_n -f||_1= \int_{(0,\infty)}\left|\frac{n}{x^3}e^{\left(-\frac{n}{2x^2}\right)}\right|dx = e^{0} - e^{-\infty} = 1$$

This means that 
$$\|f_n - f\|_1 = 1 ~~~~\forall n > 0 $$

You can conclude that $f_n$ does not converge to $0$ if one uses norm-$1$.

Comment: I don't have any indetermination when n goes to infinity? n is always positive as it is a natural number.

Comment: as I did, you have to fix $n=0$ and then $n > 0$. In the second case, you evaluate also what happens when $n \rightarrow +\infty$. Do you agree?

Comment: why do you fix n=0 if n can NOT be cero?

Comment: I dont understand how do you get $e^0-e^\infty$

Comment: ok, good point, I don't have to pose $n=0$, this case is unuseful

Comment: for me, $e^{-(n/2x^2)}\Big|_{(\infty,0)} = e^{-\frac{n}{2\cdot(+\infty)}} - e^{-\frac{n}{2\cdot(0)}}= e^{0} - e^{-\infty} = 1 - 0 = 1$ when $n > 0$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11770/discussion-between-the-candyman-and-blanca)